# What is the effect of income on an adolescent's reward response to monetary vs. social reward?

Tags: motivation, developmental-psychology, well-being

I am asking a question related to adolescents and their response to either monetary or social reward.

What is the effect of income levels on monetary vs. social reward? Do higher income children respond better to one over the other, or vice versa? Does preference for one or the other have any indications for overall self-perceived life satisfaction?

Any links to papers dealing with the issue or even similar issues will be much appreciated!

Also, it would be nice to understand the underlying neuroscience behind your answers. What is happening in the brain?
This is a very internist question!